# data passing and using json data from alamofire with swift

Tags: json, swift, server, alamofire

I integrated alamofire, but I got one problem to use data within server communication.

Before I tell about my problem I will show my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var MainViewTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var SidesOpen: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var GroupButton: UIButton!

var apps:[sample] = [sample]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    SidesOpen.target = self.revealViewController()
    SidesOpen.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    self.setUpSample()

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





func setUpSample()    {

   Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://{url}").responseJSON{ (request, response, data, error) in
        var json = JSON(data!)

        for var index = 0; index < json["store"].count; ++index{
            var marketinfo = json["store"][index]["name"].stringValue
            var imageUrl = json["store"][index]["img"].stringValue
            let sample_menu = sample(marketInfo: marketinfo, imageName: imageUrl, button: "")
            self.apps.append(sample_menu)
        }

    }
   print(self.apps)
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return apps.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print(setUpSample())

    let cell: TblCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("marketCell") as! TblCell
    let sample = apps[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell(sample.marketInfo , imageName: sample.imageName, Coupon: "s/t.jpeg")

    return cell
}
}
```

Within setUpSample function I have got one problem that I have no idea to passing or taking out JSON data. In the function I tried to print result what I can have from it however, the result was empty.

Comment: put the println inside the alamofire closure

Comment: I know it works, but It is just working inside of alamofire closure. My point is that I try to get data out from it for setting up cells within the data.

Comment: Just call tableView.reloadData() inside your closure then.